# Rails respond_to :json controller-scoped - how this syntax works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax

Suppose we've got

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  clear_respond_to
  respond_to :json
end
```

I am wondering how eg. `respond_to :json` works in Rails. I know how it behaves in case calling it with block-use inside method, like method-missing pattern. But what is going on under hood just inside class body? What is this element `respond_to` inside class? Is it some kind of method call?

Comment: Rails is open source, have a read through [the code](https://github.com/rails/rails)

Comment: Hey, I've updated question. I didn't specified exactly what I meant in first step, sorry for that.

Comment: Have you read Rails' API on respond_to? http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_to

Comment: Yeah, but I am asking about syntax, not how respond_to works. Again - here, in example - is this some method call inside class body? Like
`def meth; respond_to |format| ...; end` is clear. It's called inside method body.